# How to constrain a text element within an square with RaphaelJS?

Tags: javascript, drawing, raphael

I'm trying to constrain a text element with custom font within a square. I'm having difficulties to let the constrainment take place.

My code looks like this for the move function:

```
if (this.attr("y") > offsetY || this.attr("x") > offsetX) { // keep dragging & storing original x and y
    this.attr({
        x : this.ox + dx,
        y : this.oy + dy
    });
} else {
    nowX = Math.min(offsetX, this.ox + dx);
    nowY = Math.min(offsetY, this.oy + dy);
    nowX = Math.max(0, nowX);
    nowY = Math.max(0, nowY);
    this.attr({
        x : nowX,
        y : nowY
    });
}
```

The constrainment never takes place. However, if I use two squares with this code, it works. What am I overlooking here?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the default text-anchor value of 'middle' when you called `paper.text()`, the x and y attrs will return the coordinates of the center of the text span -- not its upper left corner, as it would with a rect.

Rather than using the `x` and `y` attributes, you should get your coordinates via [element.getBBox()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.getBBox), and then use the `x` and `y` from the resulting object.  That should enable your existing logic to work unimpeded.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion and solved it trough the bbox object!